# Why won't usb cd drive work in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mount

Cocopa external DVD drive USB 3.0/Type-C not recognized by Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell Inspiron 16 7610.

Comment: Why do you say "not recognized"? How have you tried to use it?

Comment: First of all just plugged in. Then followed recommendations at https://itsfoss.com/play-dvd-ubuntu-1310/. Nothing I've tried works.

Comment: So you're trying to play DVD-Video? Indeed your link matches the official instructions - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs - but saying you followed a remote procedure says nothing about what really happened, if there were error, etc. And says nothing about the disk you're actually trying to read nor about what happens. Please edit the question and describe **exactly** what you did, what were the results and what type of disk you're trying to read and what happens when you insert it.

Answer (score 0):

The seller has now admitted that this device does not work with Linux.